# Why does this non-zero integral evaluate to 0 in SageMath?

Tags: symbolic-math, sage, maxima, integral

I want to perform formal computations using SageMath, which involve integrals of trigonometric functions. I noticed some inconsistencies and narrowed the problem down to the following basic problem.

Why does the following source code return 0?

```
var('n t')
assume(n, 'integer')
integrate(cos(2 * pi * n * t), t, 0, 1)
```

While I agree that the integral is zero when `n` is non-zero, mathematically, the integral is worth 1 when `n` is zero. Up to my understanding, I only tell SageMath that `n` is an integer here, so it should handle the case `n = 0` also.

I checked that `integrate(cos(2 * pi * 0 * t), t, 0, 1)` correctly returns 1, so SageMath seems to be aware of this possibility, but somehow misses the fact that `n` could be 0.

What am I missing?

Comment: From what I remember, Sage calls Maxima to calculate integrals, and on the whole Maxima returns results are right for typical values, and special cases aren't covered. Although there are places in the code where Maxima will ask if a variable is zero or nonzero, these are triggered only if a corresponding special case is detected; Maxima doesn't try to analyze results to see if there are cases which aren't covered, such as n = 0 in your example. This is admittedly a deficiency. I think you can tell Sage to call Sympy to compute integrals, maybe it handles special cases better.

Comment: Thank you very much for this nice answer. Is there somewhere a related Q&A or issue ticket or explanation on the Maxima website? Do I have to open an issue somewhere? Thank you for Sympy. I will try it.

Comment: You can report some at https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/bugs/ for Maxima.

Comment: See also https://ask.sagemath.org/question/67139/why-does-this-non-zero-integral-evaluate-to-0/

Comment: @cs89 Unfortunately there isn't any straightforward documentation about stuff like this in Maxima. The history of Maxima is that it has grown incrementally over many years, and we are still working with design decisions made in the 1960's and 70's. What I was saying about the treatment of special cases is part of the unwritten but generally understood conceptual basis. If you are interested in this topic you might consider bringing it up on maxima-discuss (https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss); others who have longer experience might be able to say more about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness, Robert is right (of course!) and this is now tracked at [Maxima bug 4125](https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/bugs/4125/) and [Sage ticket 35406](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/issues/35406).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to create these 2 tickets. I was kind of surprised to find a bug for such a basic integral, but I understand the logic behind how it is implemented. My initial problem involved a product of 4 trigonometric functions with 4 unknown frequencies, so the case distinction gets nasty.

Comment: Thanks for creating the bug tracker ticket. I don't mean to be picky, but I'd just like to point out there's no reason to assume I'm right as a matter of course; I've certainly been mistaken about all kinds of stuff. All the same I sincerely appreciate your help and support.

Comment: @RobertDodier good point, but I think in this case you were right, as it was really a Maxima issue.